# how to count column values?

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by

Here's my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.STATE_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_NAME,
   r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION
FROM report_one r1
INNER JOIN report2 r2 ON r1.distributor_code = r2.distributor_code
ORDER BY r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE;
```

It's working fine. Output:
 [image: output]

But when I try to count the columns of `r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION` I get error "not a single group by function":

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.STATE_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_NAME,
   r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION,
   count(r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION) AS NumberOfDates
FROM report_one r1
INNER JOIN report2 r2 ON r1.distributor_code = r2.distributor_code
ORDER BY r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE;
```

Please can anyone help? How can I count the values?

Comment: Did you try by having only **count(r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION)** in select clause

Comment: sorry I also used group by syntax that is ....group by r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE order by r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `distinct` keyword and add a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT r1.STATE_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_NAME,
   r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION,
   count(r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION) AS NumberOfDates
FROM report_one r1
INNER JOIN report2 r2 ON r1.distributor_code = r2.distributor_code
GROUP BY r1.STATE_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_NAME,
   r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION
ORDER BY r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE;
```

EDIT:
It's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you're trying to get the number of distinct `LAST_EOD_EXECUTION` values per group, you'd need to use the `distinct` keyword inside the `count`:

```
SELECT r1.STATE_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_NAME,
   r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION,
   count(distinct r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION) AS NumberOfDates
FROM report_one r1
INNER JOIN report2 r2 ON r1.distributor_code = r2.distributor_code
GROUP BY r1.STATE_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE,
   r1.AREA_OFFICE_NAME,
   r2.LAST_EOD_EXECUTION
ORDER BY r1.AREA_OFFICE_CODE;
```

Comment: please see my output image

Comment: thank you Mr.Mureinik it's working but small mistake is you've added comma before order by clause

Comment: @VenkatSri copy-paste bug, indeed - thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.